# Drupal Navigation Title "Reset" to Use Page Title

Tags: 7, navigation

Does anyone know if there is a way to "reset" a navigation title so that it falls back in-sync with a page's title?

Please find below scenario.  Created a page with a title of "Page About Stuff." In the Main Navigation, we edited the navigation title of the page so that it was shorter (e.g., "Stuff Page"). Then we said, that's silly, let's go back to using the original page title as the navigation title.  However, now if we change the page title from the "Edit Page/Current" window (along with some other content on the page), the title of the page changes appropriately but the title within the navigation doesn't, it stay to what we manually set. My question is, is there a way to "reset" this title link so everything is back in-sync.

Share your thoughts on this?